# Request desktop html NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I am trying to parse some metadata from the head tags of various websites on iOS. Unfortunately, some of those sites (namely Vimeo) do not send the same metadata when rendering the mobile page as they do the desktop one. I need to request the html for the desktop version from these sites. Is this possible with NSURLSession? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the `User-Agent` header in your `NSURLRequest` to a value that makes the website believe you are sending the request from a non-mobile device.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: someURL]; 
[request setValue:@"some appropriate desktop user agent string" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

The [following site](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/) lists many possible user agent strings you can choose from.